# From a list of vectors, extract only one column from each vector

Tags: python

Given a list of vectors:

```
[((0, 2.6147858445098677), (1, 1.0257184186249431)), ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (2, 0.34113605903013322)), ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (3, 0.074196986667672063)), ((1, 1.0257184186249431), (2, 0.34113605903013322)), ((1, 1.0257184186249431), (3, 0.074196986667672063)), ((2, 0.34113605903013322), (3, 0.074196986667672063))]
```

how to extract only the first entry in each vector?

```
[(0, 1), (0,2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1,3), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Could just use a list comprehension. Each item is a tuple that contains two tuples, so we can parse out the first item of each inner tuple like so:

```
x = [((0, 2.6147858445098677), (1, 1.0257184186249431)), ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (2, 0.34113605903013322)), ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (3, 0.074196986667672063)), ((1, 1.0257184186249431), (2, 0.34113605903013322)), ((1, 1.0257184186249431), (3, 0.074196986667672063)), ((2, 0.34113605903013322), (3, 0.074196986667672063))]
result = [(item[0][0], item[1][0]) for item in x]
print(result)
```

outputs:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

as desired. This is very c-style, you can get a more pythonic if you want and use tuple unpacking:

```
result = [(first[0], second[0]) for  first, second in x]
```

which is a bit more understandable/readbale.

Answer (score 0):

Or `map`:

```
>>> l=[((0, 2.6147858445098677), (1, 1.0257184186249431)), ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (2, 0.34113605903013322)), ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (3, 0.074196986667672063)), ((1, 1.0257184186249431), (2, 0.34113605903013322)), ((1, 1.0257184186249431), (3, 0.074196986667672063)), ((2, 0.34113605903013322), (3, 0.074196986667672063))]
>>> list(map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[1][0]),l))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista =[
    ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (1, 1.0257184186249431)), 
    ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (2, 0.34113605903013322)),
    ((0, 2.6147858445098677), (3, 0.074196986667672063)), 
    ((1, 1.0257184186249431), (2, 0.34113605903013322)), 
    ((1, 1.0257184186249431), (3, 0.074196986667672063)), 
    ((2, 0.34113605903013322), (3, 0.074196986667672063)) ]

new_lista = []

for i in lista:
    new_lista.append((i[0][0], i[1][0]))

print(new_lista)
```

Or:

```
[new_lista.append((i[0][0], i[1][0])) for i in lista]
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 vector.py
> [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake you can also use a combination of `operator.itemgetter`, `map` and `functools.partial` (given a list `v`):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from functools import partial
list(map(tuple, map(partial(map, itemgetter(0)), v)))
```

Or it can be more concise with Python 2.7 or before:

```
map(partial(map, itemgetter(0)), v)
```